# When I move a window partially offscreen, the offscreen part shows on next/previous desktop

Tags: ubuntu, window-manager, compiz, virtual-desktop, ubuntu-11.04

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04; when I move a window partially offscreen, the offscreen part shows on the next/previous desktop

In the screenshot below you can see CompizConfig (opened on the second desktop) is moved off-screen a bit and partially shows on this desktop.

[image]

Where can I turn this off?

Comment: This is how multiple monitor desktops always work. What would you like to happen instead?

Comment: I want it to go offscreen. at least to have an outer border on the multiple desktops so when I am on the TOP RIGHT desktop,  and move the window offscreen to the RIGHT I don't want it to show on the TOP LEFT screen from the LEFT

Comment: So it's wrapping around the multiple monitors? Does the cursor wrap round along with the windows? Or is it just the Windows?

Comment: it's not multiple monitors, it's one monitor with virtual desktops. when I move the window offscreen on one virtual desktop it shows on the other one. maybe I wasn't clear enough, sorry

Comment: Ah, ok, sorry, rjmunro's comment threw me. If you run a 2x2 grid, does it also happen vertically? Seems to be a known bug/feature: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/480228

Comment: yes, it also happens vertically. thanks for the info about the bug

Answer (score 1):

This is the window manager's fault. Metacity doesn't have a way to control this, but other window managers may.

Answer (score 0):

See http://earlruby.org/2012/04/getting-rid-of-self-resizing-windows-in-ubuntu-linux-12-04/ 
for instructions on installing the CompizConfig Settings Manager and using it to get Gnome/Metacity to work the way you want.

In particular, once you have it installed, you want to click on "Window Manager", click the "Put" checkbox, then click the word "Put", "Misc Options" tab, and then click the "Avoid Offscreen" checkbox.